# Does HarmonyOS video support URL playback and how to develop?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am interested in Huawei HarmonyOS, after reading some online documents of HarmonyOS, I am still not clear whether the OS supports online URL playback. If it is supported, how to develop it. Can someone help?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, HarmonyOS video does support URL playback. Here is the sample code for you reference.

```
private void playUrl(Surface surface) {
    try {
        Source source = new Source("video url");
        mPlayer.setSource(source);
        mPlayer.setVideoSurface(surface);
        mPlayer.setPlayerCallback(new VideoPlayerCallback());
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mSurfaceProvider.setTop(0);
        mPlayer.play();
    }
}
```